# How to read data from Online JSON [url.json] and assign its value to java variable

Tags: java, android, json

I want to read some variable values from json and assign them to android java code and execute some conditions. I do not have that much knowledge about linking JSON and java but I heard that I need to use that method in order to get remote variable value that can control things in my app.

here is value.json to be uploaded in my server

```
[
  { "value1" : "1.1",
    "value2" : "5.4" },

]
```

I want to read value1 and value2 values and assign them to other public variable names in java

Comment: you no need to upload file for controlling app. Just use database value and response in json via `GET` method from Android.

Comment: 1) your JSON is not valid. JSON does not allow *trailing comas*. 2) what exactly is a problem for you to do that? You should not ask us to write the code instead of you, but if you already tried something, and something did not work, or there is something *exact*, more detailed than *how to write an application, that...*, then be more specific and tell us what exactly is a problem.

Comment: you can use firebase remote config to store your values. pls refer below post.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android

Answer (score 0):

You could manually parse the JSON yourself, but I always personally leverage a purpose built library. For Java, GSON (https://github.com/google/gson) is the most common, alternatively you could try Moshi (https://github.com/square/moshi) which is also popular.

Start by creating a model corresponding to your JSON like so;

```
public class ExampleModel {

    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
}
```

Then you can use GSON as so `Gson().fromJson(jsonstring, ExampleModel.class);` which will return an object populated with your JSON data, providing it is valid.

Answer (score -3):

You can use firebase for such data manipulation it is free of cost and you do not need any server of your own for this.